# Is There a Way to tp a player back to Spawn After Falling into Void?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a mini-game for my server and would like the lobby to be a skyisland over the void, my question is, Is there a way to tp a player back to the skyisland if they fall in the void? I have a vanilla server and don't want to use plugins or mods if possible.(maybe a command?)

Comment: if you need more information please don't hesitate to ask

Comment: have you tried making people not fall into the void but on pressureplates on top of command blocks, and then just tp them? How big is the area you are dealing with?

Comment: Is the skyisland/spawn at a specific coordinate?

Comment: its actually a large airship over the void which does not have  flat edges where I can put command blocks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a world-wide area, can use `/execute` to change the coordinate origin to that of the player, and teleport them when they reach below `y=0` (going downwards by 64 blocks):

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /tp @a[c=1,y=-1,dy=-64] X Y Z
```

Or:

```
/execute @a ~ -1 ~ /tp @a[c=1,dy=-64] X Y Z
```

Comment: could you simplify this? as I asked this question because I have no idea where to start

Comment: I would make this a excepted answer if you did

Comment: @cubelords Can you elaborate on "simplify"? It's a single command and can't be simplified further.

Comment: maybe explain how to do it more simply? what everything stands for?

Comment: like do I just type exactly what you said or should I write the coords or something in place of something?

Comment: @cubelords You need to specify where `/tp` is going to teleport the player to. "X", "Y", and "Z" are placeholders for you to replace, not numbers. The rest of the command will remain as it is. `/execute` changes the origin of command to that of the player, so `/tp` is being run at their location (and the selector is then restricted to that location, except for `y` which is set to -1, and `dy` which is looking from `-1` and 64 blocks downwards). You can find more info on the wiki about `/execute` (and commands in general) [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#execute).

Comment: ok thanks skylinerW ive seen you helping on a lot of forums xD

Answer (score 1):

`/execute @a ~ -1 ~ /tp @a[c=1,dy=-64] X Y Z`

`@a`:
player

`~ -1 ~`:
void coordinates

`/tp @a[c=1,dy=-64]`:
teleports player

`X Y Z`:
where to teleport player

Answer (score 1):

`/execute at @a run tp @a[limit=1,y=-1,dy=-64]` X Y Z
for newer versions :]